# How to solve the probability of the binomial distribution sequence below?

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

> Let $x_0$, $x_1$...$x_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables. $x_i = 1$ has probability $p$ and $x_i = 0$ has probability $1-p$. Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $x_k = x_{k+1}$. Find probability that $x_k = 1$.

Example: $1,0,0,1,1,\cdots\quad k = 1$ and  $x_k = 0$.

My idea is that the probability of $x_k = 1$ is equal to the probability that no consecutive zero occurs before, which is $1-x_k = 0$ and then this question becomes the same question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $r:=P(x_k=1)$ and $r_0:=P(x_k=1\mid x_0=0)$ and $r_1:=P(x_k=1\mid x_0=1)$.

Then we have the equalities:

- $r=pr_1+(1-p)r_0$
- $r_0=pr_1$
- $r_1=p+(1-p)r_0$

Do you see why, and can you take it from here?

---

**edit**

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 &  & 0\\
 & 1-p\nearrow &  & \nwarrow\\
\text{start } &  & p\downarrow &  & \uparrow1-p\\
 & p\searrow &  & \nearrow\\
 &  & 1\\
 &  &  & p\searrow\\
 &  &  &  & x_{k}=1
\end{array}$

Comment: Thank you! I have questions on the equalities, I think r = r1+r0 and I couldn't see why r0=pr1, could you explain it more? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added a (clumsy) picture of the situation in the hope that things become more clear. If $x_0$ has taken its value then we land in "status" $0$ or "status"1. If we are in status $0$ then we can only end up with $x_k=1$ if the next $x_i$ gives a $1$ and secondly from status $1$ we go on to status $x_k=1$. That gives $r_0=pr_1$.

Comment: $r\neq r_1+r_0$ (as you think) but $r=r_1p_1+r_0(1-p)$. In general we do not have $P(A)=P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\complement})$ but $P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^{\complement})P(B^{\complement})$

Comment: Thanks for the picture and explanation! I think I get it!

Answer (score 1):

For $x_k=1$, the first $k-1$ samples must either be: an alternating sequence of $1,0$ (and $k$ is odd) or $0$ followed by an alternating sequence of $1,0$ (and $k$ is even); and of course samples $x_k, x_{k+1}$ must then be both $1$.